# Windows inserts additional characters when pressing a key

Tags: windows-10, input-device

Since two reboots ago, Windows enters a backslash in front of every zero I type on the number row, like so: /0. This does not happen when using the numpad.

Similarly, when hitting Enter on the numpad, a two is added before the enter is accepted, like so: 2

What could be going wrong?

Comment: Have you ruled out a defective keyboard by trying it with a different keyboard?

Comment: In addition to testing the keyboard as suggested, also make sure (Accessibility Features) that there are no special accessibility keystrokes selected

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: @LPChip this only happens with my current keyboard, not with any others.

Comment: @John where can I check this exactly?

Comment: @harrymc yes, also in Safe Mode.

Comment: Your keyboard is defective if this is the only keyboard causing the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a software problem, as it also happens when booting in Safe mode.

Your keyboard is faulty, according to the test suggested by @LPChip,
as it is the only keyboard that has the problem.

It is possible that the problem is with sticky dirt under the keys,
which can be solved by (carefully) cleaning up the keyboard.
The exact procedure varies according to keyboard model.

If cleaning doesn't help, the keyboard should be replaced.